# How to create an "external module" typescript definition file to include with an npm package?

Tags: npm, typescript

I recently added [a typescript definition file](https://github.com/neilff/redux-ui-router/blob/master/index.d.ts) for the open source redux-ui-router library, but I'm now getting errors like the following with Typescript 1.7.3:

> error TS2656: Exported external package typings file
>   'C:/.../node_modules/redux-ui-router/index.d.ts' is
>   not a module. Please contact the package author to update the package
>   definition.

I am trying to import this library with code like this in my typescript files:

```
import ngReduxUiRouter from "redux-ui-router";
```

I'm new to Typescript, and I can't find a clear description of what exactly this definition file should look like when included with an npm package. [There's a wiki entry](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Typings-for-npm-packages) that talks about typings for npm packages, but outside of repeating the direction that an external module should be used, there's not a concrete example to work from.

**CORRECTION**
I've tried removing the `declare module "redux-ui-router" {` code, *and that seemed to work after restarting webpack, which I'm using to compile everything* (I removed the comments for brevity):

```
export interface ReduxUIRouterAction {
    type: string;
    payload: any;
}
export interface ReduxUIRouterState {
    currentState: Object;
    currentParams: Object;
    prevState: Object;
    prevParams: Object;
}
export function router(state: ReduxUIRouterState, action: ReduxUIRouterAction): ReduxUIRouterState;
export var ngReduxUiRouter: string;
export function stateGo(to: string, params?: Object, options?: Object): ReduxUIRouterAction;
export function stateReload(state: any): ReduxUIRouterAction;
export function stateTransitionTo(to: string, params?: Object, options?: Object): ReduxUIRouterAction;
export default ngReduxUiRouter;
```

Is this set of changes what would be expected when including this in an npm package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this set of changes what would be expected when including this in an npm package?

Yes. The exports need to be root level at the file.

In other words : *an ambient file is not an external module*