# Exported external package typings file is not a module

Tags: typescript, typing

I'm trying to write a Declaration File but at compile I get the error

> Exported external package typings file
>   '/nativescript-keychain/index.d.ts' is not a module. Please contact
>   the package author to update the package definition.

The code I'm writing it for is very simple so not sure where I'm going wrong.

```
var setPassword = function (password, appName, account) {
  SAMKeychain.setPasswordForServiceAccount(password, appName, account);
  return true;
};

var getPassword = function (appName, account) {
  return SAMKeychain.passwordForServiceAccount(appName, account);
};

exports.setPassword = setPassword;
exports.getPassword = getPassword;
```

and the index.d.ts is

```
declare module "nativescript-keychain" {

   export function setPassword(password: string, appName: string, account: string): void;
   export function getPassword(appName: string, account: string): void;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to provide typings for a module you should not make them global ( ambient ).

So just remove `declare module` and it should work.

```
// index.d.ts
export function setPassword(password: string, appName: string, account: string): void;
export function getPassword(appName: string, account: string): void;
```

You can check as an example [ImmutableJS typings](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/blob/master/dist/immutable-nonambient.d.ts)

If you want to publish your typings as a separate `d.ts` and publish it to DefinitelyTyped, you should include `declare module` in your typings.

Comment: Thanks that worked, still trying to get my head around it all.

Comment: Well this has a long story about writing `d.ts` files. You can read more at the [typings documentation](https://github.com/typings/typings/blob/master/docs/external-modules.md). . Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34030542/how-to-create-an-external-module-typescript-definition-file-to-include-with-an?rq=1 is another good read.